# (Stacked brackets) I haven't done this kind (I don't even know what to call it) of math in 5 years. I remember nothing please help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=$$

Comment: Is this vector multiplication? I don't know what you are trying to ask.

Comment: in the equation, the brackets are long with a "1" in the upper left corner, "0" in upper right, "1" in lower left, and "0" in lower right. Likewise with the second set, the 2 and 3 are upper left and right, respectively, and the 1's are lower. I couldn't get it to format correctly sorry.

Comment: I think that may be what it is called. I haven't done it in a long time. Trying to prepare for the math placement exam

Comment: The question just has those two brackets side by side with an equal sign. Trying to brush up. Sorry if I'm making it difficult to help me.

Comment: These are called matrices, and this is matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2\\b_3&b_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(a_1b_1+a_2b_3)&(a_1b_2+a_2b_4)\\(a_3b_1+a_4b_3)&(a_3b_2+a_4b_4)\end{bmatrix}$$
Hopefully you can see the pattern.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I saw this and it came back to me. I wish math was more like riding a bike. I was in AP Calc when I left high school. The way I'm struggling, you'd never know that. Ha. I digress.

Comment: To the proposer: For some people, math is like riding a bike. For others, it's like  the 3-page recipe for "crepes Suzette".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you have [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).  Your question has been edited to reflect that.  You multiply each row of the first by each column of the second, summing the products, and enter the result into the intersection.